# Creating A News Feed with Relevant Data for App

Tags: android, mysql, ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm creating an app that currently allows users to create topics, vote in topics, follow topics, and chat in topics.

Currently working on creating a News Feed like Facebook or Twitter that brings users topics that are related to what they've interacted with in the past.

I understand this a complex topic, but I would appreciate any answers anyone might have to working towards a solution.

Current solution:

Point system where topics will be added +1 to +1000 points for user activity.

For example:

```
If user creates topic, then add +50 points to topic.
```

Topic is more likely to show up on the user's news feed.

Another example:

```
If user "follows" topic, then add +25 points to topic.
```

Topic is more likely to show up on the user's news feed.

Another example:

```
If topic was created in the past 24 hours, add +24 -(number of hours since creation) to the topic.
```

Hoping to learn if there's a more practical approach to figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a look at [Facemash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848004/facemash-algorithm) / [Elo rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system#Mathematical_details) to choose between two topics
2. Do A/B testing between different points systems. Users will tell you what they like and what dislike
3. Take a look at [Reddit ranking](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588)